# Using HTML form to store to resource (Laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm creating a laravel application that allows users to create a blog post.

I have created a PostsController as a resource with store function like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    return 123;
}
```

Also, I added  a route in web.php

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
```

If I list the routes with php artisan `php artisan show:routes`, POST method is listed:

[image]

The HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="PostsController@store" method="POST">        
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="body" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

When I submit the form, I get MethodNotAllowedHttpException:

`The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.`

I used to use laravel collective for forms before. Haven't done any work in laravel for a while and now it seems to be deprecated (https://laravelcollective.com/), so I resorted to classic HTML form. How do I work around this?

Comment: Just wrap action of form in double curly braces and also add `csrf_token` field and then check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your action is incorrect within your form - you need to point the action to the URL of the route, and then the route will select the method, in this case, the 'store' method. Also add `@csrf` for more information [CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf)

```
<form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="POST">
   @csrf        
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="body" rows="3" name="body"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

add the name in textbox and textarea

```
form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="POST">
       @csrf        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="title" name="title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="body">Body</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="body" rows="3" name="body"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```